# how to Change display value from json in html

Tags: javascript, html, json, grafana, grafana-alerts

I'm using Grafana for some dashboards in my work, and then  added some alerts for that. for those who doesn't know: the alert send a json with an html template via email to show some metrics that i want to see.

the problem is that alert are kind of broken and add some zeros to my json and when i want so send a number like 1422 i receive 1422.000, when i want to send 23 i receive 23.000 and that can confuse people that receive my email.

i tried everything possible for change it from grafana and i couldn't do it so i want to try something different.

i founded that email template for those alerts and the data is showed in a table like this:

```html
{{if ne .State "ok" }}
<table class="row" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 100%; position: relative; display: block; padding: 0px;">
  <tr style="vertical-align: top; padding: 0;" align="left">
    <td class="last" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; color: #222222; font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; margin: 0; padding: 0 0px 0 0;" align="left" valign="top">
      <center style="width: 100%; min-width: 580px;">
      <table class="twelve columns" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 580px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;">
        <tr style="vertical-align: top; padding: 0;" align="left">
          <td class="six" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; width: 50%; color: #222222; font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; margin: 0; padding: 0px 0px 10px;" align="left" valign="top">
            <h5 style="font-weight: bold; color: #222222; font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.3; word-break: normal; font-size: 18px; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;" align="left">Metric name</h5>
          </td>
          <td class="six last" style="width: 100px; word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; color: #222222; font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; margin: 0; padding: 0px 0px 10px;" align="right" valign="top">
            <h5 style="font-weight: bold; color: #222222; font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.3; word-break: normal; font-size: 18px; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;" align="right">Value</h5>
          </td>
        </tr>
        {{range .EvalMatches}}
        <tr style="vertical-align: top; padding: 0;" align="left">
          <td class="six" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; width: 50%; color: #222222; font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; margin: 0; padding: 0px 0px 10px;" align="left" valign="top">
            <h5 class="data" style="color: #222222; font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; word-break: normal; font-size: 16px; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;" align="left">{{.Metric}}</h5>
          </td>
          <td class="six last" style="width: 100px; word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; color: #222222; font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; margin: 0; padding: 0px 0px 10px;" align="right" valign="top">
            <h5 class="data" style="color: #222222; font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; word-break: normal; font-size: 16px; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;" align="right">{{.Value}}</h5>
          
          </td>
        
        </tr>
        {{end}}
      </table>
      </center>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

i want to change the value in {{.value}} to a number without that zeros.

tried with {{.value | number: "0-0"}} didn't work, tried with {{.value.tofixed()}} and not work.

maybe some script but dont know what to do.

aditional data:

- Can't Change the Json

json from alert firing :

```js
{
  "firing": true,
  "state": "pending",
  "conditionEvals": "true = true",
  "timeMs": "-363.790ms",
  "matches": [
    {
      "metric": "44",
      "value": 681
    }
  "logs": [
    {
      "message": "Condition[0]: Query",
      "data": {
        "from": 1627055525472,
        "queries": [
        
    {
      "message": "Condition[0]: Eval: true, Metric: 44, Value: 681.000",
      "data": null
    }
  ]
}
```

i don't know why the data is changed

got this email
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkcvE.jpg

any help will be nice, thanks

Comment: can you change value to a string before sending?

Comment: Hi @VisakhVijayan, i didnt found the option to change that value, values must be in numbers for the dashboards work.